# how to optimize this sql in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a sql like this:

```
select t1.id,t1.type from collect t1 
 where t1.type='1' and t1.status='1' 
    and t1.total>(t1.totalComplate+t1.totalIng)  
    and id not in(
             select tid from collect_log t2 
              where t2.tid=t1.id and t2.bid='1146') 
limit 1;
```

is is ok, but its performance seems not very good and if i using a order command:

```
select t1.id,t1.type from collect t1 
 where t1.type='1' and t1.status='1' 
    and t1.total>(t1.totalComplate+t1.totalIng)  
    and id not in(
             select tid from collect_log t2 
              where t2.tid=t1.id and t2.bid='1146') 
order by t1.id asc 
limit 1;
```

it become even worse.
how can i optimize this?

here is explain:

```
id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref             | rows | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+-----+---------+-----------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | t1    | ref  | i2,i1,i3      | i1  | 4       | const,const     |   99 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | t2    | ref  | i5            | i5  | 65      | img.t1.id,const |    2 | Using where; Using index
```

Comment: It's slow because of the math being done. Have you tried putting the `and t1.total>(t1.totalComplate+t1.totalIng)` at the very end, just before the `limit`, so as to reduce the size of the result set that operation gets performed on?

Comment: What indexes do you have defined?

Comment: no Agmlauncher,i did not tried that ,how?

Comment: Subquery could have `LIMIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If it's not already done, define an index on the `collect.id` column :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_collect_id ON collect (id);
```

Or possibly a unique index if you can (if `id` is never the same for any two lines) :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_collect_id ON collect (id);
```

Maybe you need an index on `collect_log.tid` or `collect_log.bid`, too. Or even on both columns, like so :

```
CREATE INDEX idx_collect_log_tidbid ON collect (tid, bid);
```

Make it `UNIQUE` if it makes sense, that is, if no two lines have the same values for the (tid, bid) couple in the table. For instance if these queries give the same result, it *might* be possible :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM collect_log;

SELECT count(DISTINCT tid, bid) FROM collect_log;
```

But don't make it UNIQUE if you're unsure what it means.

**2)** Verify the types of the columns `collect.type`, `collect.status` and `collect_log.bid`. In your query, you are comparing them with strings, but maybe they are defined as `INT` (or `SMALLINT` or `TINYINT`...) ? In this case I advise you to drop the quotes around the numbers, because string comparisons are painfully slow compared to integer comparisons.

```
select t1.id,t1.type from collect t1 
 where t1.type=1 and t1.status=1 
    and t1.total>(t1.totalComplate+t1.totalIng)  
    and id not in(
             select tid from collect_log t2 
              where t2.tid=t1.id and t2.bid=1146) 
order by t1.id asc 
limit 1;
```

**3)** If that still doesn't help, just add [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) in front of your query, and you'll get the execution plan. Paste the results here and we can help you make some sense out of it. Actually, I would advise you to do this step *before* creating any new index.

Comment: thank you very much,i add a index of log.tid,bid but it is Normal type. well,it work fine,and the performance become good. should i change it to UNIQUE? and shortage of UNIQUE or NORMAL?

Comment: i had paste the explain on this page.

Comment: And thanks for the EXPLAIN, but unfortunately it's not very readable for me. You should use more explicit names for your indexes, I don't know what columns are used in i1, i2, i3... I suggest you rename them with the names of the columns they contain, **in the same order as in the index**, separated by _ . For instance, your index on collect_log (tid, bid) could simply be called **tid_bid**. This way, you will find it easier to read the execution plans and find out which indexes MySQL is likely to use when performing your query.

Comment: and thanks for your suggestion about how to name index,i think it really useful.

Comment: Glad I could help (and I'm not on fb). Anything else you'd like me to add to my answer? Otherwise, could you please mark it as accepted?

Comment: you don't use any social website or software?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33980/discussion-between-jason-yang-and-miklos-aubert)